# Download File to Byte[] with Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I need to download a file to byte[] using Selenium in C#.

The problem is the file is downloaded via a button which does a javascript call:

```
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$gvOutputs','Select$0')
```

If i could get a URL I could just use the C# command:

```
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Cookie] = this.GetCookieHeaderString(); //Get Cookie from Selenium window
        return wc.DownloadData(sourceURL);                
    }
```

Unfortunately this wont work as I dont have the URL.

the __dopostback makes a POST request which looks like this:

```
__EVENTTARGET=ctl00%24MainContent%24gvOutputs
__EVENTARGUMENT=Select%240
__VIEWSTATE=sEM2tcQczKVsK5kzEN2x19Gxco%....
__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=B935C9B7
    __VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED=
__EVENTVALIDATION=kOyxw5ZKBd1yygTXmUR%....
```

I suppose if there were a way to get those variables I could create a POST in C#.. However I'm not sure how I can get those variables?

I can click the link in selenium, but that will force a download to the clients computer..

I suppose 1 option would be to monitor the download directory, and read it this way, but im trying to avoid this brute force method.

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping for a better answer. However I ended up making a specific DOWNLOAD path for every Selenium instance, then monitoring that directory and associating the files with the selenium instance.. A little bit hacky but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit late, but I just found a solution for my case.
You can use this chunk of JS code to do the post request:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '<THE-POST-REQUEST-URL>', true);
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
xhr.onload = function () {
    if (this.status === 200) {
        var fileArray = this.response;
        var filename = '';
        var disposition = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
        if (disposition && disposition.indexOf('attachment') !== -1) {
            var filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
            var matches = filenameRegex.exec(disposition);
            if (matches != null && matches[1]) filename = matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, '');
        }

        var byteArray = new Uint8Array(fileArray);

        var obj = {
                'fileName': filename, 
                'fileData': byteArray
        }

        callback(obj);
    }
    else {
        callback('server error - file might not be found');
    }
};
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.send('<POST-REQUEST-ARGUMENTS>');
```

and then call it in selenium:

```
var response = driver.ExecuteAsyncScript(
  @$ "var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];
      // The rest of the code from the last example
  "
);

if (response is Dictionary < string, object > fileDict) 
{
  var fileName = fileDict["fileName"]?.ToString();
  var fileData = fileDict["fileData"];
  if (fileData is ReadOnlyCollection < object > readonlyCollection) 
  {
    var byteArray = readonlyCollection.Select(i => (byte)(int)(long) i).ToArray();
    var tempFile = "PATH/TO/FILE";
    File.WriteAllBytes(tempFile, byteArray);
  } 
  else 
  {
    throw new Exception("fileData is not a byte array");
  }
}
```